# Why is django's development static file server serving the wrong bootstrap.css?

Tags: django, mezzanine

In Django 1.6 and Mezzanine 3.1.3:

I have a app called 'theme' in which I store my theme specific extensions on a Mezzanine installation. This theme is placed above mezzanine apps in the INSTALLED_APPS.

theme contains a replacement bootstrap.css:

```
 $ django findstatic css/bootstrap.css
Found 'css/bootstrap.css' here:
  ...core/theme/static/css/bootstrap.css
  ...mezzanine/mezzanine/core/static/css/bootstrap.css
```

[I alias django=django-admin.py for convenience]

Everything works fine in production where the theme's bootstrap.css file is collected in the statics and is served correctly.

When working locally, using 'django runserver', the mezzanine bootstrap file is served, not the theme's file as the above findstatic call implies.

static settings:

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_collected')
```

Unique theme/static files are served correctly and the theme/template files correctly overwrite the mezzanine ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the client browser and not in Django.

In my case I was switching between running a server on port 8000 for various projects and working copies.

As a result, the bootstrap.css file (or other files with the same name in different projects) cached on the browser can stay there from a previous project or working copy. The browser cannot tell that the actual service has changed so that it should really be using a different file.

The fix is to clear the browser cache. In Chrome, I've just got into the habit of using the drop down menu that appears on the refetch button when the developer tools are selected to pick the "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" option whenever things look like they might be getting out of sync.